# Untar and gzip from multiple sub directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a directory which consists of multiple sub-directories. Each subdirectory
has a `tar.gz` file which on untar gives two files namely `R1.fastq` and `R2.fastq`. I want to untar the tar file and compress `R1.fastq` and `R2.fastq` immediately after piping,and save the output of each sub-directories into another SINGLE directory.

```
 sourcedir=/sdir
 destdir=/ddir

 for f in $sourcedir/*; do
    fbase=${f##*/}   
    echo "Inside $fbase"
 tar -xvf $f/*.gz |gzip -n9 $f/*.fastq > $destdir/
done
```

I wrote the above code but it goes until the `echo` command.

Comment: You cannot save the files from all the subdirectories to the same directory if the files have the same names. You should give an example of the (extracted) files in at least two subdirectories and should show the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The `$f/*.fastq` doesn't match anything  by the time that line gets invoked. But the major problem is that `tar` doesn't extract to stdout, it creates files (there would need to be some way to tell the 'receiving' on the other end of the pipe that one file ends and the other starts, and there isn't at least not with `tar`).

So when using `tar` you have to let `tar` create the files and then `gzip` the created files afterwards.

If the files fit in memory you can write a quick script in Python using `tarfile` and `gzip` modules and never let the uncompressed code touch the disc. IIRC the individual files are completely extracted, so for this to work they have to fit in memory.

Comment: R1.fastq and R2.fastq are both in 1 tar.gz file,and should be decompressed on untar,and compressed into individual .gz files.the above code does not work

Comment: @Ron That is contrary to what the question says. There you state that you decompress. Please update your question so that is correctly describes what you want to happen.

Comment: my bad.I have updated the question.It was a mistake on my part

Comment: i have updated the code which I want but its not running

Answer (score 0):

The general approach is to read the file names from the archive (unless they are always the same) and then have `tar` extract only one file at a time. GNU `tar` has the option `--to-stdout` which prevents it from writing a file. Without that you would need a FIFO for each file name.

```
> tar -tf subdir.tar.gz
R1.fastq
R1.fastq

tar -xf subdir.tar.gz --to-stdout R1.fastq | gzip -n9 >/path/to/R1.fastq.gz
tar -xf subdir.tar.gz --to-stdout R2.fastq | gzip -n9 >/path/to/R2.fastq.gz
```

Comment: i didn't get how the same command tar -xf subdir.tar.gz would --to-stdout to different files.Do i need to do pattern matching while extracting?

Comment: @Ron It's not the same. Look better.

Comment: @Ron, look closer. The `tar` commands are indeed going to `stdout`, but that is then piped into `gzip`, which throws the results into separate .gz files.

Comment: tar -tf UNCID_2193585.70c7f658-5208-4b3f-9767-27a3b06b8ddc.120409_UNC14-SN744_0226_AC0M8NACXX_4_ACTTGA.tar.gz       
           120409_UNC14-SN744_0226_AC0M8NACXX_ACTTGA_L004_2.fastq
           120409_UNC14-SN744_0226_AC0M8NACXX_ACTTGA_L004_1.fastq

Comment: For example The above shows one of the directories and it gives the name of the two files,now I should redirect this --to--stdout by piping? and pipe again then to gzip it ?

Comment: @Ron There is only one pipeline connection. `--to--stdout` makes `tar` usable for a pipeline with file extraction. The file contents are written to `/dev/stdout` instead of to a file. You can easily test this (without the pipeline) with small text files.